# ConditionalCheckFailed Exception occurs while storing an item into DynamoDB using java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am using DynamoDBMapper to save an item into DynamoDB without any condition/expression set. But I am getting ConditionalCheckFailed exception each time I save the object. Refer code below.

Note: I am running this code under 5 threads.

## Main.java

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;

AmazonDynamoDBClient db = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
Region region = Region.getRegion(regions);
db.setRegion(region);
DynamoDBMapperConfig config = new DynamoDBMapperConfig(DynamoDBMapperConfig.DEFAULT,
            new DynamoDBMapperConfig(TableNameOverride.withTableNameReplacement("myTableName")));
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(db, config);

UserDocument userDocument = new UserDocument("UD001", "TestUser");
mapper.save(userDocument);  # Getting ConditionalCheckFailed exception
```

## UserDocument.java

```
public class UserDocument {
    public UserDocument(String id, String account) {
        this.id = id;
        this.account = account;
    }

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @DynamoDBVersionAttribute
    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "account")
    public int getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(int account) {
        this.account = account;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the testclass code and values you are assigning to that object?

Comment: Hi, Added my test class "UserDocument" and the values assigned to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DynamoDB enables optimistic locking strategy to ensure that the client-side item that you are updating (or deleting) is the same as the item in DynamoDB. The annotation `@DynamoDBVersionAttribute` is used for that.

First time - Save should work successfully

Second time - You need to provide the version while calling the save. For example:-

```
userDocument.setVersion(1L);
```

**@DynamoDBVersionAttribute**

> To support optimistic locking, the AWS SDK for Java provides the
>   @DynamoDBVersionAttribute annotation. In the mapping class for your
>   table, you designate one property to store the version number, and
>   mark it using this annotation. When you save an object, the
>   corresponding item in the DynamoDB table will have an attribute that
>   stores the version number.

**To switch off the optimistic locking:-**

Set the SaveBehavior as **CLOBBER**

```
DynamoDBMapperConfig config = new DynamoDBMapperConfig(new DynamoDBMapperConfig(
                DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.CLOBBER),             
                new DynamoDBMapperConfig(TableNameOverride.withTableNameReplacement("userdocument")));
```

> To disable optimistic locking, you can change the
>   DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior enumeration value from UPDATE to
>   CLOBBER. You can do this by creating a DynamoDBMapperConfig instance
>   that skips version checking and use this instance for all your
>   requests.

[Optimistic locking](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html)